# Ubuntu 13.04 shutdown hangs in Asus A3500E

Tags: installation, shutdown, asus, 13.04, reboot

On reboot or shutdown, in a old Asus A3500E notebook, with a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 install, the process hangs and shows the messages:

"acpid: exiting"

"speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher"

I don't know if the message is something that has just been finished correctly, or is the reason for the shutdown stop...

No proprietary drivers are suggested in Ubuntu SW Center. No more updates of Ubuntu are in list.

Forcing shutdown with power button, the screen gets black, but power light maintains on. The only way is to remove battery...

Any ideas?

Comment: Even I'm facing the very same problem with Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 and yes this problem does not stick to Asus A3500E only. The very same message get displayed to me most of the time but it might also be a problem of bumblebee because once following message also get displayed **"bbswitch:enabling discrete graphics"** during shutdown.My system hangs while reboot and shutdown both. Could you please confirm that the system you are using is either equipped with Nvidia Optimus or not, so that we can rule out this possiblity. By the way I'm using Dell Inspiron n5110. Thanks...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, even during sleep, so I filed a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1173867