# Ubuntu 13.04 shutdown hangs in Asus P42F

Tags: shutdown, asus, 13.04

On shutdown the following message is displayed:

```
acpid: exiting
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

The computer hangs at this spot and does not complete a shutdown or reboot as requested.

Manually powering the machine down does work, but I cannot seem to find the culprit responsible for the system hang. I have no proprietary drivers and no updates are listed as available.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue?

I noticed a similar question here: [Ubuntu 13.04 shutdown hangs in Asus A3500E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285574/ubuntu-13-04-shutdown-hangs-in-asus-a3500e)

Comment: I'm using a Dell n4010 laptop and i have the same issue. I have to press power button to shutdown the system.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the hang up during shutdown by removing the speech-dispatcher. Not sure if that's the correct solution though but it's a temporary remedy to prevent the hang up for now.

Hope that helps.